# Get feature type of a layer

Tags: r

I have to assign the feature type of a layer.
Does anyone know an function, or way to access this information.

I have noticed that the message of the function `readOGR` (package [rgdal](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html)) contains an entry like Feature type: `wkbMultiPolygon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R spatial objects don't follow the Simple Features standard so the features types don't map to things like `wkbMultiPolygon` etc.

Note: Examples that follow use sample data sets defined from `help(readOGR)`

R spatial objects are either (usually) points, lines, or polygons. You can get the class of the object to see which it is.

```
> class(cities)
[1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
> class(scot_BNG)
[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
```

Or you can test using `inherits`:

```
> inherits(cities, "SpatialPoints")
[1] TRUE
> inherits(scot_BNG, "SpatialPoints")
[1] FALSE
> inherits(scot_BNG, "SpatialPolygons")
[1] TRUE
```

If you want the feature type of an OGR data source **before** you read it into R, you can use the `ogrinfo` function to print the feature type of an OGR-compatible data source:

```
> ogrInfo(dsn=dsn, layer="scot_BNG")
Source: "/home/rowlings/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/rgdal/vectors", layer: "scot_BNG"
Driver: ESRI Shapefile; number of rows: 56 
Feature type: wkbPolygon with 2 dimensions
[etc]
```

I don't see how this can be extracted from the function without duplicating some of the code inside it, namely:

```
> WKB <- c("wkbPoint", "wkbLineString", "wkbPolygon", "wkbMultiPoint", 
        "wkbMultiLineString", "wkbMultiPolygon", "wkbGeometryCollection")
> info = ogrInfo(dsn=dsn, layer="scot_BNG")
> WKB[info$eType]
[1] "wkbPolygon"
```

and for points:

```
> info = ogrInfo(dsn=dsn, layer="cities")
> WKB[info$eType]
[1] "wkbPoint"
```

Comment: Above all your last two examples are very helpful. I didnt't know how to use object `eType`.

Comment: well, its not documented, so it might change in later versions of rgdal.